# Set of all $x$ such that $f$ is continuous

Tags: functions, continuity

A friend of mine showed me the following question but we both cannot find a solution:

*Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the following function:*

$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{b^2} & \text{for }\frac{a}{b} = x \in \mathbb{Q},\ a,b \in \mathbb{N}\text{ and coprime}\\ 0 & \text{for }x\not\in\mathbb{Q} \end{array}\right.$

*Find the set $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\ |\ f\text{ is continuous in } x\}$.*

Could anyone please write a solution to this problem so that we can understand what is going on here?

Comment: You probably want to allow $a \in \Bbb Z$ if you don't restrict $x$ to positive values.

Comment: This set will be precisely the set of irrational numbers. Now that you know it, it should be easy for you to show that the function is discontinuous at rationals and continuous at irrationals (you will probably need two separate arguments to justify that).

Comment: @Wojowu: Let's assume that $f$ is continuous for $x_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$. So, there must be a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x_0)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x_0-x|<\delta$. Let $\epsilon$ be $>0$ and let's take an $x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x_0-x|<\delta$. It follows that $|f(x_0)-f(x)|=|f(x_0)| = \epsilon \not<\epsilon$. This is a contradiction which shows that $f$ is discontinuous at all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to continue for irrational numbers. Can you show me how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is a variation of Thomae's function.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function.  You should be able to see how this generalizes to your function.